# A fixed div element in the container div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use Bootstrap 5 and I want to create a main `div.container` section which should include a fixed div element and an additional div element with scrollable content. If the page is scrolled the fixed div element should be fixed and the content div should be scrolled under the fixed div.

I don't want a fixed navbar (with class `fixed-top`) because there is no space on the left and right side. I want to have the fixed navbar in the `div.container` with space on the left and right side.

My solution works well, only the width of the fixed div is destroyed and the width is bigger than the width of the content div. See [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u4bofacL/1/)

How do I keep the default width untouched? Should I split the `div.container` section in two separate div sections?

#### HTML

```
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
        <h1>Fixed Header</h1>
        text... 
      </div>
    
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Begin of Content</h1>
        very long text...
      </div>
    
    </div>
  </body>
```

#### CSS

```
.header {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  height: 200px; 
  background-color: green;
}

.content {
 top: 200px;
 position: relative;
 background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you vor your help. Now I found a solution what works for me. The magic word is sticky:

```
.header {
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: green;
}

.content {
 background-color: yellow;
}
```

See here https://jsfiddle.net/3xzf8d65/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it doesn't works for me. But I have already found a solution, with position value "sticky" see me answer above

Answer (score 0):

A solution to your problem may be to limit the width of the header using css, here's an example:

```
e.header {
position: fixed;
z-index: 1000;
height: 200px;
max-width: 85%;
background-color: green;
}

.content {
top: 200px;
position: relative;
background-color: yellow;
}
```

you can play around with the width percentage and even change it to px for example 'max-width: 1000px;'